# earning persistent regression interpreting

Tags: regression, interpretation, linear

Can you please help me interpret the earning persistent? Thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about economics, but I'll give it a try:
Since it is an autoregressive model, the $\beta_1$-coefficient tells you something about the relation between the current earnings ($t$) and the earnings at time $t+1$. Since your estimated $\beta_1$ is negative, you have an indication that your earnings will become lower on average in the long run.

You can given kind of an interpretation to it as follows: when your earnings at time $t$ (so $Y_t$) increase with, let's say, 1 million, it is estimated that your mean earnings at time $Y_{t+1}$ will increase with -0.24 $\times$ 1 000 000, so it will decrease with 240 000. Because of the random noise that is present, this will be lower or higher every step $t$. From this you also see why a higher $\beta_1$-value is preferred.

(Note: This is all if your assumptions for the model are valid, i.e. normality of the error term, linearity, sufficient autocorrelation, ...)

If your model is stationary, you can also estimate the mean of the long-term earnings by $\frac{\alpha}{1 - \beta_1}$.

I hope this helps you some way!